# what is the purpose of subtracting 1 from an array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am new to PHP and trying to better understand the wordpress source code.
In my travels I have come across the following line of code...

```
$lastc = $data[$length-1];
```

Can anyone tell me what the purpose of the $length-1 is within the data array?

Comment: Cannot predict programmers intentions without more info! But in this case it appears they are getting the "last character" of a string.

Comment: specifically I just need to know what -1 can do to the key. I will upload more of the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have an array:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Then the `$length`, being `count($arr)`, is 5. $data[$length - 1] is the last element (fourth index).

However, you're right to note that this reads terribly. That's why the developers should probably have just gone with:

```
$lastc = end($data);
```

Which returns the last element of an array.

If it is a string, they should use:

```
$lastc = substr($data, $length - 1);
```

Which would return the last character of the string.

Comment: I would not say `should`, but I do agree that `end()` is a cleaner way to do this

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like this code is intended to get the last character in that particular string. In PHP, you can address strings as arrays:

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world";
echo $str[6]; //outputs w;
?>
```

(see also [PHP manual](http://php.net/language.types.string)). In this case, the code seems to have the length of that particular string stored in `$length`, and so `$length-1` is the index it'll need to get the last character, because the index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

An array with length 3 has members `0`,`1` and `2`. So `array[3]` doesn't exist, but `array[3-1]` (aka `array[2]`) does.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a way to get the last element in an array. Since arrays are zero-indexed, the last element of an array is one less than the length. For example, if an array $foo has five elements, then the last element could be referenced via $foo[4].

Answer (score 0):

`$data[$length-1]` is how you get the last element of an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a way to reference the last item in an array. Since arrays start with an index of zero, and an array length is at least one (assuming the array is not empty), using $array[(count($array)-1)] will give you the last item.

If you find yourself needing the last element more often than not in a given array, I like to use array_reverse so that I can simply call $array[0].

Comment: reverse the whole array just to get the last element? that sounds like an overkill.
in php, just use end()

Comment: You're right, Jarry. That's useful as well, and had completely slipped my mind. +1 for you.

Comment: If you want more than one element, use array_slice. You still don't need to reverse the array.

Comment: You too, Benastan. These are all excellent solutions, and certainly faster and more efficient than the array_reverse method.